# Wordpress download of custom CSV file

Tags: javascript, wordpress, csv, download, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a *Javascript* download function that provides the download of a CSV file from a custom table of a specific page that is private.

The function works perfectly, if the user is logged as an Admin, in case the user is logged with any other *Wordpress* role the CSV file is blank, downloaded with no information.

Since the page is private, the content of the page is visible only for higher roles, but not even those are able to proceed with the download.

Somethings I've already tried:

- Add the *Javascript* function directly in the *PHP* archive that it will be used.
- Add the function via the *Theme Options Cold Fields* (the theme being used is Avada).
- Create a new .js file with the function in my child theme and add it to the **wp_enqueue_script** in the functions file.
- Changing the page visibility to *public*.

With all the above options the result was the same, the download works (with data) only with admin credentials.

What I need is a download file containing all the data that is visible on the table printed in the page, despite of the user being an admin or not.

Current code called at *onclick*:

```js
var filename_dwn = 'dados_inscricao.csv';

function setFileName(){
    var input = document.getElementById("fileName");
    var ext = '.csv';
    var filename = input.value;
    filename_dwn = filename+ext;
}

function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
    var csvFile;
    var downloadLink;
    csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv"});
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = filename;
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
}

function exportTableToCSV() {
    var filename = filename_dwn;
    var csv = [];
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length-2; i++) {
        var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");
        
        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++){ 
            var data = cols[j].innerText.replace(/"/g, '""');
            data = '"' + data + '"';
            row.push(data);
        }
        csv.push(row.join(","));        
    }
    downloadCSV(csv.join("\r\n"), filename);
}
```

```
function my_theme_scripts_function() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_theme_scripts_function');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Without seeing your code, how could we possibly help you? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @disinfor I believe the problem is related to the user role. but, either way I've added the code above :)